# How to split my strings with re.split?

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm beginning my adventure with regular expressions.
I'm interested in splitting specially formatted strings. If a letter is not inside parentheses it should become a different element of output list. Letters grouped inside parentheses should be put together.

Samples:

my string => wanted list

- `"ab(hpl)x"` => `['a', 'b', 'hpl', 'x']`
- `"(pck)(kx)(sd)"` => `['pck', 'kx', 'sd']`
- `"(kx)kxx(kd)"` => `['kx', 'k', 'x', 'x', 'kd']`
- `"fghk"` => `['f', 'g', 'h', 'k']`

How can it be achieved with regular expressions and `re.split`?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot be done with `re.split`, as it would require splitting on zero length matches.

From http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split:

> Note that split will never split a string on an empty pattern match.

Here is an alternative:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+(?=\))|\w)', your_string)
```

And an example:

```
>>> for s in ("ab(hpl)x", "(pck)(kx)(sd)", "(kx)kxx(kd)", "fghk"):
...     print s, " => ", re.findall(r'(\w+(?=\))|\w)', s)
... 
ab(hpl)x  =>  ['a', 'b', 'hpl', 'x']
(pck)(kx)(sd)  =>  ['pck', 'kx', 'sd']
(kx)kxx(kd)  =>  ['kx', 'k', 'x', 'x', 'kd']
fghk  =>  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'k']
```

Comment: @Maciej Ziarko: Please note that this answer, by using `'\w'` and no lookbehind assertion assumes that parenthesis will always be balanced and that you never have digits and underscores in your data.  Given your test data this is a fair assumption, so +1.

Comment: Yes, they will always be balanced. Any other characters in my data are small letters. I like both your answers and I voted them up. BTW: Can you recommend any good regular expressions tutorial/book with nice examples?

Comment: I mostly used http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for learning, and http://www.rubular.com/ is very useful for quick testing on your regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You want `findall` not `split`.  Use this re: `r'(?<=\()[a-z]+(?=\))|[a-z]'`, which works for all your test cases.

```
>>> test_cases = ["ab(hpl)x", "(pck)(kx)(sd)", "(kx)kxx(kd)", "fghk"]
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?<=\()[a-z]+(?=\))|[a-z]')
>>> for test_case in test_cases:
...     print "%-13s  =>  %s" % (test_case, pat.findall(test_case))
...
ab(hpl)x       =>  ['a', 'b', 'hpl', 'x']
(pck)(kx)(sd)  =>  ['pck', 'kx', 'sd']
(kx)kxx(kd)    =>  ['kx', 'k', 'x', 'x', 'kd']
fghk           =>  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'k']
```

**edit:**

Replace `[a-z]` with `\w` if you want to match upper and lower case letters, numbers, and underscore.  You can remove the lookbehind assertion `(?<=\()` if your parenthesis will never be unbalanced (`"abc(def"`).